# Notation for a sum product

Tags: notation, summation

I'm struggling with notation for a sum product. Let $f:Z^+\rightarrow Z^+$. I am interested in a sum where each term is the product of functions whose sum of arguments equals $n$. For example if $n=3$ then the sum product is
$$
f(3)+f(2)f(1)+f(1)f(2)+f(1)f(1)f(1)
$$
I would like to have something that looks like
$$
\sum_{?} \prod_{?} (f(j))^?
$$
and I'm most interested in the product.
The closest I get is
$$
\sum_{\Large \begin{array}{c} i_1,\ldots,i_d \\ i_1+\ldots+i_d=n \end{array}}f(i_1)\cdots f(i_d)
$$
Is it possible to go further? Is there an alternative way to express this?

Comment: What about using concept of [Compositions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Compositions+4)? [theory here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Composition.html)

Comment: Thanks for the idea @JosefZ. It's not quite what I'm looking for. I would like to make the product as explicit as possible.